# How to make i18n and sveltekit works when navigate with <a href=>

Tags: internationalization, url-routing, sveltekit

So i'm using typesafe-i18n, with everything setup and working. But now when i tried to make a nav-bar i'm having this situation.

First for the routes, it's like this

```
routes
|---[[lang]]
      |-----day-tour
      |-----night-tour
```

This is the menu items used to make the navigation links

```
export const menu_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'home',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'day_tour',
        url: 'day-tour',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'night_tour',
        url: 'night-tour',
    },
]
```

and the nav-link

```
<section
    class="[&>.router-link-exact-active]:bg-secondary hidden items-center gap-1 text-sm font-bold uppercase md:flex">
    {#each menu_items as { url, id, text } (id)}
        <a
            href={url}
            class="hover:bg-secondary px-3 py-[2px] transition-all duration-500"
            >{$LL.nav_bar[text]()}
        </a>
    {/each}
</section>
```

so when i click "Home" it will take me to `localhost:5173/` instead of `localhost:5173/en`
and "Day Tours" will take me to `localhost:5173/day-tours` instead of `localhost:5173/en/day-tours`

and what more, if i'm at `localhost:5173/en/day-tours` click again it will lead me to `localhost:5173/en/day-tours/day-tous`

i still don't know how to deal with this. Anyone have any ideas ?

I look through some topic and asking about the trailingslash, i edited it from never to always in +page.ts so it works for the first click `localhost:5173/en/day-tours` but then next click will then duplicate the href to `localhost:5173/en/day-tours/day-tours`